# How to make Mapbox draw a connecting line between successive points in a Point layer

Tags: mapbox

I have a dataset which consists of individual point coordinates for various objects.
I would like to display the coordinates as points on a map layer.
I also want a line to be displayed between each successive point to connect the dots.

I added the source as geometry type 'Point' with an array of point coordinates.
I added the layer as 'type': 'circle'
This displays the points as expected.

I searched the Mapbox documentation for a way to make the point layer connect the points with a line. I could not find any way to do this.

How can I make the Point style draw a connecting line bewteen successive points in a Point layer?

Answer (score 0):

Using Mapbox lines and dots should be in distinct layers.  So if you want a line connecting dots use a layer with a `type: line` and have it consume a source of a geometry of `lineString`. [This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/) has a clear code sample of how to implement a line based on coordinates.

To add dots (as well as the line), use the coordinates you have now, as the sources, and use the `addLayer` with the `type: circle` as you have and you'll have your dots rendered on top of the line.

This gives you more control over styling your layers.